# Render infinito en useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Colegas, tengo un pequeño problema al querer actualizar de forma automática cuando ocurra un cambio en mi componente. 
Estoy usando `hooks` para mostrar información desde una `API`, el problema es que cuando trato de implementar **[useEffect](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)** para que actualice el componente cuando ocurran cambios, este entra en una *renderización* eterna.

```
function Docs(props) {
   const [data, setData] = useState([])

   useEffect(() => {
      getEndpoints()
   }, [data])

   const getEndpoint = async () => {
      await fetch(url)
         .then(res => res.json())
         .then(res => setData(res))
   }
}
```

Tengo entendido que si especificas como segundo parámetro del `useEffect` el dato que quieres estar "observando", el componente se actualizará automáticamente, cosa que hace de hecho, pero me causa mucho ruido que al realizar un `console.log` no deje de renderizar.

Como siempre, cualquier info se agradece

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente tuve que abarcar el problema desde otro ángulo y usar 2 `useEffect`

El primero se encarga de obtener el listado de los **endpoints** dependiendo la ruta a la que se accede

```
useEffect(() => {
   getEndpoints()
}, [props.history.location.pathname])
```

El segundo, se encarga de actualizar los datos cuando se modifican, controlando mediante el cierre de un modal

```
useEffect(() => {
   getEndpoints()
}, [modalIsOpen.open])
```

Demás está decir que si alguien tiene una solución más efectiva, será bienvenida, ya que con el segundo `useEffect` estoy trayendo toda la info otra vez desde la BD y no actualizando sólo un registro como debería hacerse.